# Describe my "special" table to views

Tags: views

I'm developing a module, and there is a table that needs views integration. The table is not so special, but can't find a solution yet.

This is how my table looks:
**nid_a|nid_b|data**

I would like to join this table to the node base table, with nid_a as joining key, and nid_b should come from a contextual filter (aka argument).

How can I achieve this?

System: Drupal 7.x and Views 3.x

Comment: What version of drupal?

Comment: Have you read the documentation [here](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!views!views.api.php/function/hook_views_data/7)? It should tell you what you need. If not, feel free to come back with more specific questions.

Comment: Yes, I'm using hook_views_data() to describe my table. The problem is, on $data['my_table']['join'] array it should consider a contextual filter as a second joining condition

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom module and use the hook_views_Data. [Here is a link for doing that](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/docs!docs.php/function/hook_views_data/6)